# Getting value from MYSQL, adding 1 and inserting into new entry

Tags: mysql

I am trying to make a stored procedure in MySQL that will take the highest number from a column, add one and use it to make the next entry.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ops_software.create_invoice;

DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE ops_software.create_invoice(IN company VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
    
    SELECT @old_invoice_number := MAX(invoice_number) 
    FROM invoices
    WHERE invoices.company = company;
    
    SET @new_invoice_number := @old_invoice_number + 1
    
    INSERT INTO invoices (company, invoice_number)
    VALUES (company, @new_invoice_number)
    

END//

DELIMITER ;

CALL ops_software.create_invoice('Super Company')
```

I don't want to use the auto-increment feature because there are several different company names and each has their own invoice numbers

Getting the value works, but I can't add one to it or insert it to make a new entry

Thanks

Comment: *I don't want to use the auto-increment feature because there are several different company names and each has their own invoice numbers* Do you need the transactions support for this table? MyISAM may provide needed functionality (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html).

Comment: A number of your statements are missing terminators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE ops_software.create_invoice(IN in_company VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO invoices (company, invoice_number)
SELECT in_company, MAX(invoices.invoice_number) + 1 
FROM invoices
WHERE invoices.company = in_company;
```

`DELIMITER` and `BEGIN-END` not needed.

PS. May produce duplicates in concurrent environment.